# Why user is able to connect to to site using CSOM when he is not authorized

Tags: 2013, development, csom

I am using the following code to connect to a site using CSOM in C# application.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://myserver");
Web web = context.Web;

context.Load(web);
context.ExecuteQuery();

MessageBox.Show(web.Title);
```

The code successfully displays title of site. But the user who is running this C# application doesn't have rights to open this site. So why is this user able to read title using this code?

Comment: did you give restricted reader/ restricted interface for translation permission to EveryOne?

Comment: No the user doesn't have any permission. I even checked it from "Check Permissions" section inside "Site Permissions" where you can see which permissions have been assigned to any user or group.

Comment: Turns out there was a bug in the code. There is another piece of code which I didn't posted above (I thought it is not relevant) and removing it fixed the problem.